# реализация Linkedlist + интересная задача

Tags: java, list

Есть 4 вида кубиков с разной плотностью, но с одинаковым объемом. Из кубиков можно составить столбик и рассчитать силу, с которой они действуют на поверхность. Можно добавлять кубики и убирать, соответственно только сверху этого столба. (плотность * объем = масса. Масса на 9,81 = сила). Как мне реализовать это все через LinkedList? По заданию именно этот метод мне нужно использовать!

Comment: Вопросы, связанные с выполнением домашнего задания кем-то за вас здесь не приветствуются. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Захотелось порешать задачки)

```
class Cube{
    private final int volume = 3;
    private double density, power;

    public Cube(int density) {
        this.density = density;
        power = 9.81 * density * volume;
    }

    public double getPower(){
        return power;
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double power = 0;
        LinkedList<Cube> column = new LinkedList<>();
        //добавляем кубики
        column.addFirst(new Cube(10));
        column.addFirst(new Cube(20));
        column.addFirst(new Cube(30));
        column.addFirst(new Cube(40));
        //перечисляем кубики в "столбике", суммируем массу каждого и выводим результат
        for (Cube cube : column) {
            power += cube.getPower();
        }
        System.out.println("Количество кубиков: " + column.size() + ", сила на поверхность: " + power);
        power = 0;
        //удаляем один верхний кубик
        column.removeFirst();
        //перечисляем и выводим
        for (Cube cube : column) {
            power += cube.getPower();
        }
        System.out.println("Количество кубиков: " + column.size() + ", сила на поверхность: " + power);
    }
}
```